# What is the proper way of updating navigation properties in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In my EF Core solution I have the following model:

```
public class Deal
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ResponsiblePerson ResponsiblePerson1 { get; set; }

    public ResponsiblePerson ResponsiblePerson2 { get; set; }

    public ResponsiblePerson ResponsiblePerson3 { get; set; }
}

public class ResponsiblePerson
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to update Deal navigations properties:

```
private void UpdateResponsiblePersons(string dealId, string person1Id, string person2Id, string person3Id)
{
    var existingdeal = _dbContext.Deals
        .Include(d => d.ResponsiblePerson1)
        .Include(d => d.ResponsiblePerson2)
        .Include(d => d.ResponsiblePerson3)
        .Single(d => d.Id == dealId);

    existingDeal.ResponsiblePerson1 = new ResponsiblePerson { Id = person1Id };
    existingDeal.ResponsiblePerson2 = new ResponsiblePerson { Id = person2Id };
    existingDeal.ResponsiblePerson3 = new ResponsiblePerson { Id = person3Id };

    _dbContext.Entry(deal.ResponsiblePerson1).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    _dbContext.Entry(deal.ResponsiblePerson3).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    _dbContext.Entry(deal.ResponsiblePerson3).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

EF often fails with

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ResponsiblePerson' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

That is because sometimes `existingdeal` already contains the link to `ResponsiblePerson` with one of provided IDs in either `ResponsiblePerson1` of `ResponsiblePerson2` or `ResponsiblePerson3` Navigation properties.

I know that one of possible solutions will be first to get ResponsiblePersons used for update from dbContext like
`existingDeal.ResponsiblePerson1 = _dbContext.ResponsiblePersons.Find(person1Id)`
But that means extra DB roundtrips.

Another solution is to expose foreign keys instead of navigation properties but it would make `Deal` model quite ugly.

Please advice me what is the best way of updating such references?

Comment: Check which `ResponsiblePersonX`s already have one of the Ids?

Comment: @GertArnold In case of more complex `Deal` entity with more related `ResponsiblePersons` we need to write and maintain plenty of `if`s..

Comment: Maybe that shows you should change your model. Looks like `Deal` should have a collection of `ResponsiblePerson`s.

Comment: I had hope that EF Core provides some clean mechanism of updating such references.

Comment: Since .NET 5 or 6, EF Core supports [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) relationships. Haven't tried it myself, but I think you should be able to call `postEntity.Tags.AddRange(/* Tags from the database */);` and `await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`